# How many trees have $n$ nodes with fewer than three neighbors?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

We want to know how many trees have $n$ nodes with fewer than three neighbors.  For $n=1$, the only possibility is a single node.  For $n=2$, the only possibility is two connected nodes.  For $n=3$, the only possibilities are a node adjacent to three nodes or a node adjacent to two nodes.  A set of drawings produces the following (possibly incorrect) sequence: $1$, $1$, $2$, $4$, $9$, $25$, $70$.  My question is whether this enumeration is a new problem or one that has been dealt with.  See [OEIS A335342](https://oeis.org/A335342).

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+9%2C+19 ?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained.  While a descriptive title is good, you should not remove the question from the body of the post.

Comment: Are you thinking of isomorphism classes? If instead we count labeled trees on $N$ vertices, the number of such trees with given degree sequence $d_1,\dots, d_N$ is the multinomial coefficient $\binom{N-2}{d_1-1,\dots, d_N-1}$, from which it ought to be possible to derive a reasonably closed expression (summing over the possible values for $N$).

Comment: These are not labeled trees.

Comment: It might be easier to first try to figure out the number of trees having $n_1$ nodes with one neighbor and $n_2$ nodes with two neighbors.

Comment: The revised sequence is not in OEIS (https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+9%2C+25%2C+70  ), so, if it's correct, you should submit it.

Comment: What kind of answer would you like?  An asymptotic formula?

Comment: I need to check it for correctness.  I do a lot of OEIS submissions.

Comment: Re answer:  I think I can work out a method along the lines of free trees, but I don't want to do the work if someone already has.

Comment: 1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 25, 70 are correct and it continues 226, 753, 2675, 9785, 37087, 143487, 566952 (the last one is for 14). For parameter 14, the number of vertices is 14-26, with counts like this: 1, 127, 2091, 13744, 48236, 102116, 140588, 130263, 82616, 35419, 9961, 1655, 135.

Comment: 2274967 for parameter 15.  Getting up to about 20 is plausible.

Comment: I have just submitted A335342 to the OEIS. It includes a Mathematica program and a B-file for n<=60 (about 7 minutes on my 2010 iMac).  The results match those in the latest comments.  Thanks for all the help; I guess we are done here.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some observations which may inform a partial enumeration.

Such a tree has $t+n$ vertices, where the $l$ leaves are part of the $n$ nodes and the rest of the $n$ nodes look like they are interior vertices that are part of a path.  The $t$ vertices each have three or more branches, so we must have $3t \lt n+t+t-1$, where the $t-1$ is a correction for over counting edges between two branch vertices. This means $t \leq n-2$.

Now if $t$ is $0$, the only tree is a path, while if $t=1$ there is a bijection between these trees and partitions of $n$ into at least three parts.  For larger $t$, we need to decide on how to arrange and color the edges between the $t$ nodes. For $t=2$ we need to decide how many of the n nodes go between, and then make sure there are at least four leftover to distribute among the remaining branches.  For $t=3$, there are two internal edges to color with a total of $0$ up to $n-5$ nodes, and then distribute the remainder on the leafy portions, being sure to save at least one for the middle $t$ node.

We now see that this becomes a problem of counting branchy trees on $t$ nodes, and then partitioning $n$ nodes on the edges, and then worrying about overcounting.  At this point I leave the problem to the professionals.

Gerhard "Neither Professional Accountant Nor Gardener" Paseman, 2020.06.04.